# Teleport - django custom tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

Help please with a django custom tag. Analize it please!

Idea:

1. In any template (parent or child), we installing a tag {{ telepoint "head" }}, with a name, such putters could be more than one.
2. At other side, we have block

   ```
   {{ teleputter "head" "unique-name" }} some html {{ teleputterend }}
   ```

   Content of this block goes to telepoint with appropriate telepoint name.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish. Please elaborate.

Comment: I am trying to do similar to inheritance {{ extend }} feature, but for {{ include }} templates and with possibility to send not one, but many blocks, to one container

Comment: So in the template you would have a {{telepoint}} tag and this tag would be replaced with the content of what's in {{teleputter}}? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: you understand right, but replaced with all teleputters concatanated content.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you are trying to implement template inheritance:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#id1

Read the full documentation for the best explanation. The Readers Digest version follows.

Essentially you have a base template with blocks of content with default values:

```
base.html
{% block  head %} "Default html goes here"  {% endblock %}
```

Next you create another template that extends the base template and build the blocks you would like to replace:

```
anotherTemplate.html
{% extends "base.html %}
{% block  head %} "This replaces the html in the base head block"  {% endblock %}
```

It sounds to me that your "telepoint" is a block in the base template and your "teleputter" is a block that extends the base template

Does this sound like what you are trying to do? Is what you are trying to implement any different?

Comment: I was already saying, that it looks like inheritance, but its not
Difference:
1. teleputter - could find telepoint from template that added as include
2. block in inheritance could fill only one time
3. inheritance means i will use only one child template, but I do components that I'll including